# Jquery not displaying UL or LI tags in html

Tags: jquery, html, tags

I have a simple code:

```
//preview copy as it's being typed
$('#copyText').keyup(function(e){
    $('#copyPreview').html($('#copyText').val());
});
```

when a user enters html - they can see a preview of what it will look like when they save it.

```
However certain tags such as <ul> and <li> are not appearing. Other HTML works such as line breaks, bold, tables, even styles... just not lists (so far, from what I see)
```

You can assume it's not the css, as I checked that.

sample text:

```
<b>All models are UL recognized <br><b>Important:</b> <br>
<ul><li>Adjustable range from -73 to 316°C (-100 to 600°F)</li>
<li>Resolution sensitivity of -17.7°C</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you post an example string containing those tags that isn't working correctly? My guess is that those strings aren't valid html.

Comment: You'll probably have to escape the HTML entities in order to have them displayed as text instead of rendering those items.

Comment: what is copytext? a text area?

Comment: @PSL - copyText is a textarea. copyPreview is a div....

Comment: @tree Can you give a sample html that is previewed and doesn't display as expected..

Comment: @PSL and Brad M - I made updates

Comment: Check here http://jsfiddle.net/9Khnz/ It works as expected.

Comment: Thanks. My code looks just like that. Sigh. Thanks. I guess it's gotta be something pretty random causing this.

Answer (score 0):

[`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is used to

> Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements

User `html()` instead

```
$('#copyPreview').html($('#copyText').html())
```

Comment: What? This is wrong, `html()` does not get the "text" from an `<input>` or `<textarea>` element.

Comment: That just shows me the same information as what they are typing and not the preview of what it will look like in a browser.